# Rails alias url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, alias

In my rails app I got controller `AboutAdministratorsController`. 
For going from page with list of administrators to administrator's detail page I use this tag

```
<%= link_to about_administrator_path(about_administrator), class: "about_people_elem" do %>
...
<% end %>
```

The route is administrator's detail page is:

```
get '/about_administrators/:id', :to => 'static_pages#administratorshow', :as => :about_administrator
```

In this case url will be

```
http://localhost:3000/about_administrators/1
```

How to implement alias for changing url to

```
http://localhost:3000/administrators/1
```

Thnx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just change the routes

```
get '/administrators/:id', :to => 'static_pages#administratorshow', :as => :about_administrator
```

If you want both the URLs to work, keep both routes.